Verification for alternative proof of Stein-Shakarchi's $\epsilon \mapsto z_\epsilon$ problem
There's this exercise in  Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis book that goes:
Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing $|z| \leq 1$. Suppose that $f$ has a simple zero at $z = 0$ and vanishes nowhere else in $|z| \leq 1$.
Let $f_\epsilon(z) = f(z) + \epsilon g(z)$ and show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then (a) $f_\epsilon$ has a unique zero in $|z| \leq 1$, and (b) if $z_\epsilon$ is this zero, the mapping $\epsilon \mapsto z_\epsilon$ is continuous.
For (a) one can get a lower bound $m > 0$ for $|f|$ in $\partial\Bbb D$ because it doesn't vanish here, and one can get an upper bound for $|g|$ $M$ in $\Bbb D$, then let $\epsilon < \frac{m}{M}$ and from here  apply Rouché's Theorem and the result follows because of the simple zero of $f$. My question is about proving (b). I tried proving it as in any standard $\epsilon - \delta$ proof of continuity, but when I came here to see whether my solution was correct I found answers proving it in a different way, and as they are more complicated I'm assuming there's a hidden mistake in my approach that I'm not seeing.
So in my "proof" we fix some $\epsilon$ as above and let $z_\epsilon$ be the associated zero, let $\alpha$ > 0 be arbitrary, then we just want $\delta > 0$ to be such that when $c$ is another real number as in (a) with $|\epsilon - c| < \delta$ we get that the associated zeros $|z_\epsilon - z_c| < \alpha$, this gives a neighborhood of $z_\epsilon$ that we can use (assuming $\alpha$ is small enough so that the neighborhood is contained in $\Bbb D$). Since we know that $f_\epsilon$'s only zero is at $z_\epsilon$ we can also get a lower bound greater than zero for it in the boundary of this neighborhood mimicking what we did in (a) and because $f_c(z) = f(z) + cg(z) = f_\epsilon(z) + (c-\epsilon)g(z)$ why not just let $\delta$ be small enough so that $|c - \epsilon||g(z)|$ is less than this lower bound and apply Rouché's Theorem one more time to conclude that $f_\epsilon$ and $f_c$ have the same amount of zeros in this neighborhood of $z_\epsilon$. We already know these zeros are unique for each of these functions so it follows that $|z_\epsilon - z_c| < \alpha$ and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that the mapping is continuous for all $\epsilon$ as in (a).
Does this have a mistake somewhere in there or is it correct?. I also never use the fact that the zero of $f$ is at $z = 0$ so that makes me assume even more that there's something wrong...
